# Is there a way to get the name of column of the result of a query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I need to get the column name of the result from case query, Is there a way to do it?

```
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN a >= b AND a >= c AND a >= d AND a >= e THEN a
        WHEN b >= c AND b >= d AND b >= e THEN b
        WHEN c >= d AND c >= e THEN c
        WHEN d >= e THEN d
        ELSE          e
    END) as ans 
FROM response
where qno='1'
```

The code above gives the value of either a,b,c,d,e but I want one of a,b,c,d,e as the result

Comment: Can show us how is your expected output please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN a >= b AND a >= c AND a >= d AND a >= e THEN a
        WHEN b >= c AND b >= d AND b >= e THEN b
        WHEN c >= d AND c >= e THEN c
        WHEN d >= e THEN d
        ELSE e
    END as ans,
    CASE
        WHEN a >= b AND a >= c AND a >= d AND a >= e THEN 'a'
        WHEN b >= c AND b >= d AND b >= e THEN 'b'
        WHEN c >= d AND c >= e THEN 'c'
        WHEN d >= e THEN 'd'
        ELSE 'e'
    END as column
FROM response
where qno='1'
```

You can also simplify this by using the `GREATEST()` function.

```
SELECT 
    GREATEST(a, b, c, d, e) AS ans,
    CASE GREATEST(a, b, c, d, e)
        WHEN a THEN 'a'
        WHEN b THEN 'b'
        WHEN c THEN 'c'
        WHEN d THEN 'd'
        ELSE 'e'
    END AS column
FROM response
WHERE qno = '1'
```